# Finding a vector equation

Tags: vector-analysis

I need to find the directional derivative of a vector. However the direction of the line is given in the form $(x-1)/2 = (y-3)/-2 = z$  form. How do I find the vector equation for the direction from the above equation. The point where we need to find the directional derivative is $(1,1,1).$

See the question below

QUESTION: Find the directional derivative of  M = 5*x^2*y -5*y^2*z + 2.5 z^2 x at the point p(1,1,1) in the direction of the line (x-1)/2 = (y-3)/-2 = z

Advanced Engineering Mathematics (B.S. Grewal) Vector calculus and it's application

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-3}{-2}=z=t$, so $x=1+2t, y=3-2t, z=t$, so $r=(1,3,0)+t(2,-2,1)$.

Comment: What will i substitute inplace of k if i want to find a equation with no variable the value of z =1 from (1,1,1) or something else. Because I tried putting that value and the ans for unit directional vector didn't match. Unit (A) = (2i -2j+k) /3 .

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** In response to the new question.

You are given the function $M(x,y,z) = 5x^2y -5y^2z + 2.5 z^2 x$ and wish to know its directional derivative at the point $p = (1,1,1)$ in the direction of the line $(x-1)/2=(y-3)/(-2) = z$. As we discussed before, the points on this line are of the form $(1,3,0) + t(2,-2,1)$ for real values of $t$, and so the unit direction vectors for this line are $\pm u$ where
$$
    u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2 + 3^2}}(1,3,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(1,3,0).
$$
We now compute $D_uM(1,1,1) = \nabla f(1,1,1) \cdot u$. First, note
$$
    \nabla f(x,y,z) = (f_x,f_y,f_z) = (10xy+2.5z^2,5x^2-10yz,-5y^2+5zx)
$$
so that
$$
    \nabla f(1,1,1) = (12.5,-5,0).
$$
Therefore
$$
    D_uM(1,1,1) = (12.5,-5,0)\cdot (1/\sqrt{10})(1,3,0) = (1/\sqrt{10})(12.5-15) = -2.5/\sqrt{10}
$$
or $-\sqrt{5}/2$. If they wished for you to compute the directional derivative along the opposite direction $-u$ for the given line, nothing above changes except the sign of the entries in $u$ in the last step, leaving you with $D_{-u}M(1,1,1) = \sqrt{5}/2$ instead.

Comment: What will i substitute in place of k if i want to find a equation with no variable. the value of z =1 from (1,1,1) or something else? Because I tried putting that value and the ans for unit directional vector didn't match. Unit (A) = (2i -2j+k) /3

Comment: Could you edit your original post to include exactly what the question says? The point $(1,1,1)$ isn't on the line you provided, and if this is a Calc 2 or 3 course I'd be surprised to see [directional derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of vector-valued functions come up much.

Regardless, there should be no "plugging in for $k$" involved in your solution, since $k$ is just the vector $(0,0,1)$ (not a variable). The vector $(2i-2j+k)/3 = (2/3,-2/3,1/3)$ is (ct'd in next comment)

Comment: (ct'd from last comment) the unit directional derivative, $v'(t)/\|v'(t)\|$ at all values of $t$ (and in particular at $t = 1$, if that's what you meant by $(1,1,1)$. So I imagine they were asking for something like the unit length directional derivative of a parametrization of this line with some restriction/orientation assumption so that you don't get the opposite vector $-(2i-2j+k)/3$.

Comment: this is not a part of my homework. I'm just working on some problems from the book for my exam.  Actually I made another post with the exact question. Didn't know if this post  was posted or not (site didn't redirect) so would it be okay to delete this post? New here.

Comment: Okay sorry this isn't the same post which i tried posting twice. Okay I will change it to the question

Comment: @Shivji: I've updated my answer to provide a solution to your new question. In the future, it's usually better under the circumstances to either delete the duplicate question rather than asking a new question after people have already posted answers, but here this is fine.